# Using flourish lib, double quotes in email subject are not fetched: FETCH command issue

Tags: imap, fetch

When I check with the FETCH command, I get like this:

2148 FETCH (UID 2159 INTERNALDATE "06-Nov-2013 06:36:15 +0000" RFC822.SIZE 3702 ENVELOPE ("Wed, 6 Nov 2013 12:06:39 +0530" {19} Reg: "test subject" (("karthick kumar" NIL "ngkarthick" "aroxo.com")) (("karthick kumar" NIL "ngkarthick" "aroxo.com")) (("karthick kumar" NIL "ngkarthick" "aroxo.com")) ((NIL NIL "phpkarthick" "gmail.com")) NIL NIL NIL ""))

There is some thing unwanted {19} in fetch command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had solved this issue by doing some pattern replace and successfully resolved and fetch all Email ,
below are my code which help me achive this

please add this code to fMailbox.php after the line

$output = array();
line no nearly 1117

```
    $response = $this -> write('FETCH ' . $messages . ' (UID INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE ENVELOPE)');
    $hintter = implode(' ', $response);
    $pattern = '(\{[0-9]+\})';

    if (preg_match($pattern, $hintter, $match)) {

        $responses = preg_replace($pattern, '', $response);
        $responsesnew = array();
        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($responses as $reps) {

            if (substr(trim($reps), 0, 1) != '*') {
                $responsesnew[$i] = $responses[$j - 1] . $reps;
                $i++;
            }

            $j++;

        }
    } else {
        $responsesnew = $response;
    }
```

and change the foreach parameters to

```
foreach ($responsesnew as $line)
```

from

```
 foreach ($responsesnew as $line)
```

Answer (score 1):

The {19} followed by a `CRLF` is called a literal. It says the next 19 characters are to read and fetched without any additional interpretation. They are part of the IMAP protocol, and they are one way that strings with difficult characters can be transferred.   They are used to transmit bodies, usually, since they tend to have CRLFs of their own.

In this case, the server has decided to transfer the subject like this, so it doesn't have to escape the quotes, that would otherwise be significant to the protocol.

Perhaps your library is not entirely protocol compliant?

Comment: when i have double quotes(") in email subject this happen  and i cant fetch the email, if there is no double quotes in email then this {19} no apper and email are read out easily

Comment: 2149 FETCH (UID 2160 INTERNALDATE "06-Nov-2013 08:04:43 +0000" RFC822.SIZE 1965 ENVELOPE ("Wed, 6 Nov 2013 13:36:13 +0530" "Reg: test's sub" (("karthick kumar" NIL "phpkarthick" "gmail.com")) (("karthick kumar" NIL "phpkarthick" "gmail.com")) (("karthick kumar" NIL "phpkarthick" "gmail.com")) ((NIL NIL "ngkarthick" "aroxo.com")) NIL NIL NIL ""))  this is the FETCH Command when , i have no double quotes in email subject

Comment: I understand that, your library or code is broken if it doesn't interpret the {19} correctly.  Again, literals are a core part of the IMAP protocol, and need to be handled at any location where a string can occur.  See RFC 3501.

Comment: Although, if there's no newline after the {19} like your post implies, then your server is broken, but I assume you're just left it out.